# how can I access the string array stored in jcr node?

Tags: java, aem, jcr

In my jcr node I have the key `subpage` and it holds the value of type `String[]`:

```
{"title":"some title1", "url":"some url1"}
{"title":"some title2", "url":"some url2"}
{"title":"some title3", "url":"some url3"}
{"title":"some title4", "url":"some url4"}
```

how can I access it in java?

I tried:

```
ValueMap contentValueMap = resource.getValueMap();

String subpages = contentValueMap.get("subpage", String.class);

System.out.println(subpages);
```

but it only prints the first string:

```
{"title":"some title1", "url":"some url1"}
```

how can I reach the rest of them?

Comment: thanks, I can use it, but I don't know how to proceed, or rather - how it can be helpful in my case :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this should work-

```
String[] subpages = contentValueMap.get("subpage", String[].class);
```

Comment: of course it works. how come I haven't tried it before :| thanks man!

Answer (score 4):

As awd mentions

```
String[] subPages = contentValueMap.get("subpage", String[].class);
```

works and is the recommended solution. This is accessing data at Sling layer. Just incase you need to dive deeper and access at JCR layer, code will look like

```
Node node=resource.adaptTo(Node.class);
Value[] subPages = node.getProperty("subpage").getValues();
```

This will be helpful for Node level operations. But it is advisable to work at higher layers at Sling or AEM.